# What is causing <Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0 when implementing loadView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a ViewController that did this in loadView:

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

Sometimes this results in the following errors on the console:

*: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.*

If you call `[super loadView]` instead, this doesn't happen.

Why?

Comment: Similar questions seem to indicate this may be nothing.

Are you using interface builder files (xib's)?  If your view controller uses those, you shouldn't write a loadView method. Also, are you using any 3rd-party frameworks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen if you try do do things in or to a graphics context before you have one. 
You can see the same on OS X. 
Make sure your view is actually in a view hierarchy that is in a window. 
Core Graphics / Quartz, does not give you a graphics context without a window. 
On iOS there is one window. 
subclasses of UIView can use viewDidMoveToWindow or viewDidMoveToSuperview as good times to check if the window is not nil and the superview is not nil. 
That tells you that it should be possible to get a valid context. 
NSView also has similar methods you can override.

I've. Seen Apple apps on OS X also spew the same messages to the Console though, so if it is being emitted by Apple framework code you might not be able  to anything about it except file a bug.

In this case init will give you a UIVIew but it is not the designated initializer which is initWithFrame: and same for NSView on OS X. So your view has no frame and this no coordinate space. So at some point code is called that needs a valid graphics context when you have no valid context. It might be your code, it might be framework code. Some undocumented things happen in undocumented orders. Normally you should not need to worry about it if you use the recommended methods and do things in the right order.

So you need to have a frame property set before you try to do anything requiring a valid CGContext. You also need to ensure you have a valid CGContext when you try to alter it. 
The error says CGContextSetCTM which is a CGContext function to set the transformation on the graphics context. It is easy to do the same with CGContextGetCTM. If the context passed in is invalid, this error would spew out. So, the question is, is it your code? or somebody else's?

Consider the following in a UIViewController subclass

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.aView = [[UIView alloc] init];
//  self.aView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
// Uncomment the above line and your error will go away. Not because you set a size greater than zero, but because you set an origin point and a size for the frame.
// Set the frame after the view is in the window view hierarchy and the error will stop occurring.
    self.aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.aView];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// This context is actually NULL.
    CGAffineTransform CTM = CGContextGetCTM(context);
// Above line will give you a nice similar error. (get instead of set)
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

We don't know if the op is using Autolayout or not. Not enough code was posted.
If you add satisfiable NSLayoutConstraints, the Autolayout system will create the origin point and thus a valid CGContext can be created.
But the crux of the matter is the origin point and size of the from must be set before the context can be accessed or modified because without it, you have a NULL CGContext.
With Autolayout the constraints must be added before the context is accessed or modified.
With manual layout frames, the frame (zero rect or otherwise) must be set before the context is accessed or modified.

The reason the designated initializer asks for it is because it is the safest time to ensure nothing is hitting the CGContext while it is NULL.

You can absolutely set a CGZeroRect as your frame in initWithFrame: and you should with Autolayout.
You can absolutely still get away with using init instead, though undocumented, as long as you set a frame or add constraints before anything hits your CGContext.
It's not documented so it's risky. 
You should always use initWithFrame: if you are not using a xib/nib/storyboard (those will get the frame from the xib/nib/storyboard in initWithCoder: )

The best advice is still to use the designated initializer, but the truth is that a CGContext cannot actually exist before the view has moved to a valid view hierarchy in a valid window, as the context is derived from the parent view context in a valid hierarchy in a window.

Comment: You can create a UIView with init, but then later set the frame property at any time. The context itself does not get created until the view is added as a subview or root view in a valid window. The frame is not even used until the first drawing/layout pass.
Autolayout does this. It calculates things at the last minute. But even without it, you do not and should not really need a frame until the last minute. initWithFrame: just saves you from the late work. 
The error is easy to reproduce if you try to set or get the CTM before you have a valid context, or pass it an invalid CGContextRef.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this could happen when a view tries to create a `CGContextRef` with empty bounds (`CGRectZero`). To make sure this doesn't happen you should give the view a frame when initializing. I usually use

```
[UIView initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
```

Comment: yip, A zero rect makes for bad calculations

Comment: With autolayout you absolutely can provide a zero rect. The key is that the designated initializer sets up other things that are required